# SSL_read decipher error code

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

Consider the following piece of code that shows an attempt to read `buff_size` bytes from ssl connection.

```
int bytes = SSL_read(m_ssl, buf, buff_size);
int err = SSL_get_error(m_ssl, bytes);
int err2 = ERR_get_error();
```

There are some cases where the variable `err` represent valid error in the code above, while `err2` act as if there's no error at all (=0).

For example, Here's a case I've encountered on my tests : when `SSL_read` tried to read 0 bytes (buffer_size = bytes = 0), `err` will show SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL. However `err2` still will be 0, indicating that there was no real error. SSL_read return this value just to indicate that 0 bytes was written to the buf.

Are there any more such special cases where `err` point that something might be wrong, but there's no read error on read result ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ssl_get_error)

> **SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL**
>
> Some I/O error occurred. The OpenSSL error queue ***may*** contain more information on the error. **If the error queue is empty (i.e. ERR_get_error() returns 0), ret can be used to find out more about the error: If ret == 0, an EOF was observed that violates the protocol. If ret == -1, the underlying BIO reported an I/O error** (for socket I/O on Unix systems, consult errno for details).
> <sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

Comment: Hi, I've read this man page, but i'm still not sure Perhaps you can provide a short code or  pseudo code to emphasis the error handling for SSL_read ?